Dita XML(Oxygen XML editer)
System ID: C:\Users\chandrapal.gautam\Desktop\Gutor-GBMS_User-Guide_0000509775_01_en (1).docx
Severity: warning
Description: Unrecognized "Table Paragraph" style for "p" Word element. You can configure the mapping between styles and elements in the Batch Documents Converter preferences page.
how to resolve this problem in DITA XML

This problem is not related to how the DITA XML standard works. You are probably using the Oxygen XML Batch Documents Converter add-on to convert Microsoft Word documents to DITA XML content.
As the error says, in the Oxygen "Preferences" dialog you should find a preferences page for the Batch Documents Converter add-on where you can configure how various specific Microsoft Word styles map to HTML elements.
Some useful links below:
https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/26.1/ug-editor/topics/batch-converter-addon.html#batch-converter-addon__section_ow5_vw4_3rb
https://blog.oxygenxml.com/topics/migrating_word_to_dita_bdc/migrating_word_to_dita_using_batch_documents_converter.html
